# Basic code works on all browsers except IE

Tags: javascript

I am able to use this code to display a PDF document except on Internet Explorer.

It says:

ReferenceError: 'fetch' is undefined

I can't find much about this. What can I do to make it work?

```
   fetch("data:application/pdf;base64," + vm.documentData.base64Document).then(function(response) {
        response.blob().then(function(blob) {
            document.querySelector("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob) + "#view=fit";
        });
    });
```

Comment: take a look at this: https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the 'isomorphic-fetch' module to your 'package.json' and then import this.

```
npm install --save isomorphic-fetch es6-promise
```

Then in your code

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch

Comment: I'm using angularJS. Is this ok? Maybe there is a cleaner way without important more stuff?

Comment: I'm using npm. But I didn't want to import external libs that I don't know off

Comment: You need to import for it to work on older browsers.

Comment: I'm using AngularJS not NodeJS. `import "isomorphic-fetch"` gives me errors

Comment: Could you then try adding a couple cdn:
`<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>`
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>`